# iOS Phonegap swipe detection using gesture

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

Hi How to use **swipe gesture**  in ***iOS and Phonegap***

I have used some plugins but it doesnt work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: r u working with jquery or jquery mobile?

Comment: im working in jQuery Mobile @Krishnaraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**Jquery Mobile**

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

**Github**

https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin